# Creating ListView with Cutom adapter dynamically in any activity class

Tags: android

How to create a simple list view using only array adapter and getview. Without using ListActivity and setAdapter in Android. Please elaborate with sample code.

**Edit :**
I was beginner and was so confused and unfamiliar with asking question on stack overflow.
Actually I was finding solution to create a adapter and list view dynamically in any activity class. Hopes downvoted will be recount again !!!

Comment: Do you know what you are asking for ?

Comment: I edited my question to regret my mistake as i was newbie to android and was blocked to ask further questions here ... i tried hard to help others and getting back my previledge .. only upvote can save me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you looking for this?

**SampleListActivity.java**

```
package com.academy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SampleListActivity extends Activity {

     private String[] mStrings = {
                "Abbaye de Belloc", "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
                "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis"};

     private ListView listView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStrings));

    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I need ArrayAdapter and getView also to do some further operation with the list items, like differentiating between different list items(text color, icon and all). How to do that ??

Comment: Read this article http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html
Because you need to implement your own adapter to create custom list.

Comment: In above articles all the examples are given with istActivity, i want the same functionalities without ListActivity. Is it possible ?? If yes, how ???

Comment: Yes, its possible. Just looking for code behind. You must create widget in your layout and initialize it in your code and set adapter.
`listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStrings));`